# Error "toggle is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html

tengo la siguiente inquietud: Mi código funciona, pero al ver la consola me arroja "ReferenceError: toggle is not defined"

Acá dejo el código

```
<div class="container-menu" id="icon-menu">
    <div class="bar-1"></div>
    <div class="bar-2"></div>
    <div class="bar-3"></div>
</div>


window.onload = function(){ 

    var icoMenu = document.getElementById('icon-menu');

    icoMenu.onclick = function myFunction() {
        icoMenu.classList.toggle('changeMenu');
    }
    icoMenu.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);   

};
```

Alguna solución ?

Comment: ¿Dónde estás ejecutando tu código? A mí no me aparece ningún error en la consola. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2epy1k3L/)

Comment: @Error404 desde Wordpress

Comment: La verdad que nunca he usado Wordpress pero supongo que será por la situación del script. Si te fijas, en el link que te he puesto en el comentario no aparece ningún error en consola debido a que lo carga onload. En caso de que lo cambies a "no-wrap in body" entonces aparece ese error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El error es que la función `toggle` no esta definida.

Al ver tu código, hay algo que pareciera estar de mas... ¿por que?

- Asignas a `icoMenu` en el `onclick`, que ejecute `myFunction`
- Luego usando `addEventListener`, para que en el evento `click`, ejecute `toggle` (función que no existe)

Aparentemente uno de los 2 esta de más, no?

Una solución seria la siguiente:

```js
window.onload = function(){ 
    var icoMenu = document.getElementById('icon-menu');
  
    function toggle() {
        icoMenu.classList.toggle('changeMenu');
    }
    icoMenu.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
}
```

```css
.container-menu {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.container-menu.changeMenu {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-menu" id="icon-menu">
    <div class="bar-1">Bar 1</div>
    <div class="bar-2">Bar 2</div>
    <div class="bar-3">Bar 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciona, perfecta solución !